# find searching in parent directories instead of subdirectories

Tags: shell, find

I'm nested deep in a file tree, and I'd like to find which parent directory contains a file.

E.g. I'm in a set of nested GIT repositories and want to find the `.git` directory controlling the files I'm currently at. I'd hope for something like

```
find -searchup -iname ".git"
```

Comment: I wish this was build in!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

An even more general version that allows using `find` options:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
path="$1"
shift 1
while [[ $path != / ]];
do
    find "$path" -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 "$@"
    # Note: if you want to ignore symlinks, use "$(realpath -s "$path"/..)"
    path="$(readlink -f "$path"/..)"
done
```

For example (assuming the script is saved as `find_up.sh`)

```
find_up.sh some_dir -iname "foo*bar" -execdir pwd \;
```

...will print the names of all of `some_dir`'s ancestors (including itself) up to `/` in which a file with the pattern is found.

When using `readlink -f` the above script will follow symlinks on the way up, as noted in the comments. You can use `realpath -s` instead, if you want to follow paths up by name ("/foo/bar" will go up to "foo" even if "bar" is a symlink) - however that requires installing `realpath` which isn't installed by default on most platforms.

Comment: the trouble with these is the way it resolves links.   for example if i'm in ~/foo/bar , and bar is a symlink to /some/other/place, then ~/foo and ~/ will never be searched.

Comment: @ErikAronesty, you're right - updated the answer. You can use `realpath -s` to get the behaviour you want.

Comment: that works when you specify a full path to search.   sadly, on centos 5.8, realpath -s <dir> has a bug where if <dir> is relative, then it resolves symlinks anyway... despite it's documentation.

Comment: `readlink` is not part of the standard. A portable script could be implemented with only POSIX shell features.

Comment: FYI, this doesn't work in zsh because it redefines $path so the shell can't find `find` or `readlink`. I suggest changing it to something like `$curpath` instead so it doesn't shadow the shell variable.

Answer (score 47):

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

will print out the top level directory of the current repository, if you are in one.

Other related options:

```
# `pwd` is inside a git-controlled repository
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
# `pwd` is inside the .git directory
git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir

# path to the .git directory (may be relative or absolute)
git rev-parse --git-dir

# inverses of each other:
# `pwd` relative to root of repository
git rev-parse --show-prefix
# root of repository relative to `pwd`
git rev-parse --show-cdup
```

Comment: This works only for git itself.  The question is more generic.

Comment: This will not work in a bare repo,

Comment: thanks great way to find file at root of git repo.e.g. ```user_file_path=$(realpath $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)/$user_file)```

Answer (score 38):

A generalized version of Gilles' answer, first parameter used to find match:

```
find-up () {
  path=$(pwd)
  while [[ "$path" != "" && ! -e "$path/$1" ]]; do
    path=${path%/*}
  done
  echo "$path"
}
```

Keeps the use of sym-links.

Answer (score 22):

If you're using zsh with extended globbing enabled, you can do it with a oneliner:

```
(../)#.git(:h)   # relative path to containing directory, eg. '../../..', '.'
(../)#.git(:a)   # absolute path to actual file, eg. '/home/you/src/prj1/.git'
(../)#.git(:a:h) # absolute path to containing directory, eg. '/home/you/src/prj1'
```

---

Explanation (quoted from [`man zshexpn`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshexpn)):

> **Recursive Globbing**
>
> A pathname component of the form `(foo/)#` matches a path consisting of zero or more directories matching the pattern foo. As a shorthand, `**/` is equivalent to `(*/)#`.
>
> **Modifiers**
>
> After the optional word designator, you can add a sequence of one or more of the following modifiers, each preceded by a ':'. These modifiers also work on the result of filename generation and parameter expansion, except where noted.
>
> - **a**
>
>   - Turn a file name into an absolute path: prepends the current directory, if necessary, and resolves any use of '..' and '.'
> - **A**
>
>   - As '**a**', but also resolve use of symbolic links where possible. Note that resolution of '..' occurs before resolution of symbolic links. This call is equivalent to a unless your system has the `realpath` system call (modern systems do).
> - **h**
>
>   - Remove a trailing pathname component, leaving the head. This works like '`dirname`'.

Credits: `Faux` on `#zsh` for the initial suggestion of using `(../)#.git(:h)`.

Comment: This is amazing... If I could only figure out (hint: _you should tell me_) what `(../)` is doing... Oh, and who/what is `Faux on #zsh`?

Comment: @alexgray `(../)` alone doesn't mean much, but `(../)#` means try to expand the pattern inside the parenthesis 0 or more times, and only use the ones that actually exist on the filesystem.  Because we're expanding from 0 to n parent directories, we effectively search upwards to the root of the file system (note: you probably want to add something after the pattern to make it meaningful, but for enlightenment execute `print -l (../)#`).  And `#zsh` is an IRC channel, `Faux` is a username on it.  `Faux` suggested the solution, therefore the credit.

Comment: That will expand all of them. You may want: `(../)#.git(/Y1:a:h)` to stop at the first found one (with a recent version of zsh)

Comment: Very helpful, thanks. To enable extended globbing do `setopt extended_glob`

Answer (score 15):

Find can't do it. I can't think of anything simpler than a shell loop. (Untested, assumes there is no `/.git`)

```
git_root=$(pwd -P 2>/dev/null || command pwd)
while [ ! -e "$git_root/.git" ]; do
  git_root=${git_root%/*}
  if [ "$git_root" = "" ]; then break; fi
done
```

For the specific case of a git repository, you can let git do the work for you.

```
git_root=$(GIT_EDITOR=echo git config -e)
git_root=${git_root%/*}
```

Comment: Cool, this puts me on a path for a general solution - which I post as another answer here.

Answer (score 4):

Recursion can result in a quite concise solution.

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

parent-find() {
  local file="$1"
  local dir="$2"

  test -e "$dir/$file" && echo "$dir" && return 0
  [ '/' = "$dir" ] && return 1

  parent-find "$file" "$(dirname "$dir")"
}

# Example
parent-find .bashrc "/home/user/projects/parent-find" 
# should respond with "/home/user"
```

Comment: This is actually really good! Thanks

Comment: `local dir="${2:-$PWD}"`   <-- now you can initiate the loop with just first argument.

Comment: Similar trick:   `local file="$1?Usage $0 <target> [start-directory]"`  will bomb out without at least one arg with a hint to the user.

Comment: @DanGarthwaite, I did not know that was possible. Thanks for sharing that!

Comment: I noticed $0 doesn't work right in a function.  So instead use the function name.

Comment: This doesn't work when the directory to be searched is `.`

Comment: @MartinPecka, you can consider converting a relative path to an absolute one either in this function or when passing the argument to it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4175264/how-to-retrieve-absolute-path-given-relative

Answer (score 3):

## Answer

Since there's a zsh one-liner here's a more general unix oneish-liner to search the **3** parent directories:

```bsh
$ name=fileOrDirName
$ eval find ./$(printf "{$(echo %{1..4}q,)}" | sed 's/ /\.\.\//g')/ -maxdepth 1 -name $name
```

## Explanation

I'll admit it's not the prettiest command, but it's one line. To search **4** directories up replace `echo %{1..4}q,` with `echo %{1..5}q,`. Specify the file or directory's name with the name variable.

In short `$(printf ... | sed ...)` is substituted for its output using [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) which is then expanded with `find` using [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html). Broken into two commands it looks like this (with a copy and paste in the middle):

```
$ printf "{$(echo %{1..4}q,)}" | sed 's/ /\.\.\//g'
{'',../'',../../'',../../../'',}
$ #copy and paste the output

$ find ./{'',../'',../../'',../../../'',} -maxdepth 1 -name $name
```

You can learn more about shell expansions with `man bash` or in the resources below on the [gnu website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html)

Answer (score 1):

This version of findup supports "find" syntax, like @sinelaw's answer, but also support symlinks without needing realpath.  It also supports an optional "stop at" feature, so this works: `findup .:~ -name foo` ... searches for foo without passing the home dir.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

# get optional root dir
IFS=":" && arg=($1)
shift 1
path=${arg[0]}
root=${arg[1]}
[[ $root ]] || root=/
# resolve home dir
eval root=$root

# use "cd" to prevent symlinks from resolving
cd $path
while [[ "$cur" != "$root" && "$cur" != "/" ]];
do
    cur="$(pwd)"
    find  "$cur/"  -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 "$@"
    cd ..
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Vincent Scheib's [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/22215/20133) doesn't work for files that reside in the root directory.

The following version does, and also lets you pass the starting dir as the 1st argument.

```
find-up() {
    path="$(realpath -s "$1")"

    while ! [ -e "$path"/"$2" ] && [ -n "$path" ]; do
        path="${path%/*}"
    done

    [ -e "$path"/"$2" ] && echo "$path"/"$2"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my one-liner tested only on bash.
It stops before it looks in the root though, so you'd have to look there manually. But hey, it's rare to put files in the root, right?

```
f=file_to_find
p=$(pwd)
until [ $p == "/" ]; do
    if [ -f "$p/$f" ]; then
        echo $f is in $p;
        break;
    fi;
    p=$(dirname $p);
done;
```

Comment: Note that you need `dirname "$p"` with quotes for the same reasons you have quotes in `[ -f "$p/$f" ]`. You could also just do `while true; do ... if [ "$p" = / ]; then break; fi; done` to test the condition in the end. (Also that's rather too complex for one line, esp. since you have to scroll horizontally to view it.)

Answer (score 0):

I've found that working with symlinks kill some of the other options. Especially the git specific answers. I've halfway created my own favorite out of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/13474/79415) original answer that's pretty effecient.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# usage: upsearch .git

function upsearch () {
    origdir=${2-`pwd`}
    test / == "$PWD" && cd "$origdir" && return || \
    test -e "$1" && echo "$PWD" && cd "$origdir" && return || \
    cd .. && upsearch "$1" "$origdir"
}
```

I'm using symlinks for my go projects because go wants source code in a certain location and I like to keep my projects under ~/projects. I create the project in $GOPATH/src and symlink them to ~/projects. So running `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` prints out the $GOPATH directory, not the ~/projects directory. This solution solves that problem.

I realize this is a very specific situation, but I think the solution is valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I modified [sinelaw's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/35265/238373) to be POSIX. It doesn't follow symlinks and includes searching the root directory by using a do while loop.

```
find-up:
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

set -e # exit on error
# Use cd and pwd to not follow symlinks.
# Unlike find, default to current directory if no arguments given.
directory="$(cd "${1:-.}"; pwd)"

shift 1 # shift off the first argument, so only options remain

while :; do
  # POSIX, but gets "Permission denied" on private directories.
  # Use || true to allow errors without exiting on error.
  find "$directory" -path "${directory%/}/*/*" -prune -o ! -path "$directory" "$@" -print || true

  # Equivalent, but -mindepth and -maxdepth aren't POSIX.
  # find "$directory" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 "$@"

  if [ "$directory" = '/' ]; then
    break # End do while loop
  else
    directory=$(dirname "$directory")
  fi
done
```