# Is there a way to find a file in an inverse recursive search?

Tags: bash, find

So say I'm in a directory that is deep within a file structure, such as

```
/home/cory/projects/foo/bar/bash/baz
```

I know that in either the current folder `baz` or one of the folders *above* me (such as `home`, `cory`, `projects`, `foo`, `bar`, or `bash`) there is a file named `happy`.  How can I find that file without searching a lot of extra folders?

Comment: Why is this, older question, closed with a link to a newer one? Looks unreasonable to me - "already has an answer" would better fit to that other, newer question.

Comment: I don’t think relative age is the primary determining factor when deciding which to close. The other question does seem to have a bit more activity and through ness in its answers so my guess is that factored into the decision.

Comment: But you don't know whether the more on traffic is an effect of closing this question. :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

function upsearch () {
    test / == "$PWD" && return || test -e "$1" && echo "found: " "$PWD" && return || cd .. && upsearch "$1"
}
```

This function will walk up from the current dir. Note, that it is a function, and will change the directory, while traversing. It will stop in the directory, where it finds the file, and will walk up to the root / if not.

You might want to change it to a script instead of a function, and maybe jump back, if the file isn't found in the root directory.

If you never want to cd to the dir:

```
upsearch () {
  local slashes=${PWD//[^\/]/}
  local directory="$PWD"
  for (( n=${#slashes}; n>0; --n ))
  do
    test -e "$directory/$1" && echo "$directory/$1" && return 
    directory="$directory/.."
  done
}
```

This will lead to results like /home/cory/a/b/c/../../../happy if the file is in /home/cory/. If you need a cleaned path, you could do some

```
cd "$directory"
echo "$PWD"
cd -
```

on success.

To restrict the search to regular files and excludes directories, symbolic links and the like, you can change the tests to -f instead of -e.

Comment: Remember to quote your expansions. If `$PWD` has a space in your test will be broken by wordsplitting.

Comment: I added masking to the directories. Is it correct now? It will still fail with special characters like '*' in filenames, won't it?

Comment: Alternatively, without function or recursion: `filePath="$(while [ ! -f "happy" -a / != "$PWD" ]; do cd .. ;done; [ / != "$PWD" ] && echo $PWD || echo .)"`

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the `-mindepth` and `-maxdepth` options to `find`.

`find` won't traverse directories in a backwards direction, but you can approach it in the regular direction and limit the depth of the search.

For example:

```
find /home /home/cory /home/cory/projects /home/cory/projects/foo /home/cory/projects/foo/bar /home/cory/projects/foo/bar/bash -maxdepth 0 -name happy -print
```

Comment: That's not going to help. Either you use `-maxdepth 0` or `-maxdepth 1`, in which case `find` isn't useful, or you don't, in which case you traverse plenty of extraneous directories for no reason.

Comment: It is a working solution. I have added an example to clarify this.

Comment: You're missing the step where you generate the list of directories from `$PWD` or some argument. And if you're going to do that, you don't need find (ok, you can call it, but it won't be very useful).

Comment: The question was "How can I find that file without searching a lot of extra folders?". I accept that this might not be the most elegant solution, but it gets the job done without searching any extra folders.

Answer (score 1):

I improved on @user-unknown's solution a bit by saving the current dir, performing an arbitrary test, then restoring the original dir before returning with response.  It's more flexible because you can test for anything.

I also provide for an optional second argument that says how high to go.

https://gist.github.com/1577473

```
#!/bin/bash

# Use this script instead of ~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt
# and the output of rvm-prompt will show up in your command prompt
# only if you are in a Ruby project directory.

# see http://stackoverflow.com/a/4264351/270511
# and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13464/is-there-a-way-to-find-a-file-in-an-inverse-recursive-search

upsearch () {
  the_test=$1
  up_to=$2
  curdir=`pwd`
  result=1

  while [[ "`pwd`" != "$up_to" && "`pwd`" != '/' ]]; do
    if eval "[[ $the_test ]]"; then
      result=0
      break
    fi
    cd ..
  done
  cd $curdir
  return $result
}

if upsearch '-e Gemfile || ! -z "$(shopt -s nullglob; echo *.gemspec *.rb)"' ; then
  ~/.rvm/bin/rvm-prompt
fi
```